# Tensorflow profiling timeline inconsistent results

Tags: tensorflow, profiling

I want to profile my Tensorflow models using the timeline feature.
The issue is that I get inconsistent total runtime results.

### Wall time

Apart from Tesnorflow timeline I am also using time.time() to meassure the runtime.

The first sess.run takes about: 1.6s
My second sess.run takes about: 0.03s

This makes sense as Tensorflow initializes some optimization related stuff first. But I can't see that in the timeline trace picture.

### Timeline

[image]

Each run takes approx. 0.3s instead of 1.6s and 0.03s.

### Code

I have loaded my graph before.

```
import os
import tempfile
import json
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import time

class TimeLiner:
    _timeline_dict = None

    def update_timeline(self, chrome_trace):
        # convert crome trace to python dict
        chrome_trace_dict = json.loads(chrome_trace)
        # for first run store full trace
        if self._timeline_dict is None:
            self._timeline_dict = chrome_trace_dict
        # for other - update only time consumption, not definitions
        else:
            for event in chrome_trace_dict['traceEvents']:
                # events time consumption started with 'ts' prefix
                if 'ts' in event:
                    self._timeline_dict['traceEvents'].append(event)

    def save(self, f_name):
        with open(f_name, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self._timeline_dict, f)


with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    # add additional options to trace the session execution
    options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

    input = graph.get_tensor_by_name("inference/input_1_1:0")
    output = graph.get_tensor_by_name("inference/output_node0:0")

    many_runs_timeline = TimeLiner()
    for i in range(2):
        start_time = time.time()
        print(len(sess.run(output,feed_dict={input: np.ones((1,256,640,3))}, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)))
        stop_time = time.time()
        print(stop_time - start_time)  

        # Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json file
        fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
        chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format(show_memory=True,
                                            show_dataflow=True)
        many_runs_timeline.update_timeline(chrome_trace)

    many_runs_timeline.save('timeline_merged2.json')
```